# Passing data with higher-order components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to remove the duplication by using a higher-order component in react.
I have two components that are retrieving the same data, displaying a circular progress until it's available then use the data when it's available.

```
import { CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

function getData(id: number) {
  return id === -1 ? undefined : `Value for ${id}`;
}

function ComponentA(props: { id: number }): JSX.Element {
  const data = getData(props.id);

  if (!data) return <CircularProgress />;
  return <>`Showing ${data} in component A`</>;
}

function ComponentB(props: { id: number }): JSX.Element {
  const data = getData(props.id);

  if (!data) return <CircularProgress />;
  return <>`Showing ${data} in component B`</>;
}
```

I was thinking of creating a function to pass the data but I was wondering if there was a better solution:

```
function withData(id: number, render: (data: string) => JSX.Element) {
  const data = getData(id);

  if (!data) return <CircularProgress />;
  return render(data);
}

function ComponentC(props: { data: string }): JSX.Element {
  return <>`Showing ${props.data} in component C`</>;
}

// To be used like this: withData(id, (data) => <ComponentC data={data} />);
```

Comment: any specific reason why to not use context?.... and what about to create array of objects with info inside each objct, and then just to loop and create your components from the array based on the object fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is not a Higher-Order Component (HOC) won't work. A HOC is a function returning a React Component (so a function of function).

> Your solution might still work however but it doesn't respect the convention of React developments.

Besides if you need to use a HOC in some other situations, consider using a function accepting a React component as argument instead of a render function. It will be better follow official documentation and will be more readable for other developers.

The solution below would work:

```
function withAddCircularProgress(Component: React.FC<Props & {id: number}>) {

  return function ({ id, ...props}) {
    const data = getData(id);

    if (!data) return <CircularProgress />;
    return <Component {...props} data={data} />;
  }
}

function ComponentC(props: { data: string }): JSX.Element {
  return <>`Showing ${props.data} in component C`</>;
}

const ComponentCWithCircularProgress = withData(ComponentC);

// to use <ComponentCWithCircularProgress id={2} {/*...other props */} />
```

You also may want to investigate a ligther alternative solution that doesn't use HOC:

```
function ShowIfData (props: {id: number, children React.ReactNode }) {
   const data = getData(id);

  if (!data) return <CircularProgress />;
  return children(data);
}

function ComponentA(props: { id: number }): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ShowIfData id={id}>
      {(data) => (
        <>`Showing ${data} in component A`</>
      )}
    </ShowIfData>
  )
}

function ComponentB(props: { id: number }): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ShowIfData id={id}>
      {(data) => (
        <>`Showing ${data} in component B`</>
      )}
    </ShowIfData>
  )
}
```

However using a component and the `children` property will have some cons: the children will be mounted in the virtual DOM whatever the condition is true or false (it won't be mounted to real DOM however). So depending how heavy the component `<>Showing ${data} in component A</>`, it might be better to avoid this solution.

Comment: note `<Component {...props} />` does not pass the `id` to the inner component

Comment: I think it was the goal based on the initial provided code. But I updated my code to forward data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay, in `ShowIfData`, how is passed the data to the children?

Comment: I updated the alternative solution to pass data too.